# Display specific dates in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using bootstrap date picker in my project. It's a session booking project. From the admin panel, I add the sessions for specific dates and I want the user's of my website to be able to see the dates for which I have added a session. My frontend receives the data from database. The data contains all the dates for which I have added a session. I want my datepicker to display only these dates from the data and disable the other dates. 
Currently I have temporarily used a select box to solve this issue. But a datepicker would be better as it looks good is easy to navigate.

See the picture below. This is how I have used a select box to temporarily solve the problem
[image: this is how I have used a select box to temporarily solve the problem]

Here is the desired output that I want

[image: It should be a datepicker with only those dates enabled which I receive from the database. The other dates should be disabled]

It should be a datepicker with only those dates enabled which I receive from the database. The other dates should be disabled
I tried searching it on google but I'm not able to find the solution. Is this possible using bootstrap date picker? If yes, please suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `beforeShowDay` function to enable only the dates returned from your back end system.

Documentation [here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#beforeshowday)

This function is executed for every date, it checks if it is present in the list of applicable dates, returns `true` if present and enables it, else returns `false` and disables it.

```
$(function () {
  let enabledDates = ['2018-10-03', '2018-10-04', '2018-10-05', '2018-10-06', '2018-10-07', '2018-10-08'];
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
      let fullDate = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();
      return enabledDates.indexOf(fullDate) != -1
    }
  });
});
```

`beforeShowDay` function also allows you to return classes for custom styling

```
beforeShowDay: function (date) {
  let fullDate = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();
  if (enabledDates.indexOf(fullDate) != -1) {
    return {
      classes: 'enabled',
      tooltip: 'You can select this date'
    };
  } else
    return false
}


.enabled {
  background: #DCDCDC;
}
```

Comment: But it has disabled all my dates. I will read the documentation.

Comment: I found a demo related to this. He has also done it the way you have suggested me to. but it doesn't seem to work for him as well. Please check his demo here https://davidwalsh.name/jquery-datepicker-disable-days Might be an issue with the calender

Comment: The link you've posted is using `jquery` plugin, the code I've posted and your question references `bootstrap-datepicker`. Are there any console errors? You can add `console.log` or `alert` inside the function to see whats happening.

Comment: Its not showing disabled for dates with zero in front of the days such as 01-11-2019 but accepts 1-11-2019

Answer (score 1):

None of the other solutions worked for me so here is my solution.

The [documentation](http://beforeShowDay) is not so clear and lacks of example but you can see a function that takes a date as a parameter and returns a **Boolean, indicating whether or not this date is selectable**

In this snippet, look at January 2020 for example in order to see only the active dates.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var datesEnabled = [
    '2021-01-01', '2021-01-11', '2021-01-21',
    '2021-02-01', '2021-02-11', '2021-02-21',
    '2021-03-01', '2021-03-11', '2021-03-21',
    '2021-04-01', '2021-04-11', '2021-04-21',
    '2021-05-01', '2021-05-11', '2021-05-21'
  ];


  $("#datepicker-lorem").datepicker({
    language: "fr",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    todayBtn: true,
    title: 'Test ;-)',
    weekStart: 1,
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    // On n'active que les dates possibles
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var allDates = date.getFullYear() + "-" + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
      if (datesEnabled.indexOf(allDates) != -1) {
        return {
          classes: 'date-possible',
          tooltip: 'Vous pouvez choisir cette date'
        }
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

  });

});
```

```css
/* For better frontend result, add class to active date and add opacity to disabled date */

td.day.disabled {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

td.date-possible {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.fr.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <input class="form-text form-control" type="text" id="datepicker-lorem" name="date_demande" value="" size="60" maxlength="128">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 'beforeShowDay' parameter you can disable dates:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//jqueryui.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jqueryui.com/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            //date list that you want to disable
            disableddates = ['10-10-2018', '10-11-2018', '10-12-2018'];
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                    var m = date.getMonth();
                    var d = date.getDate();
                    var y = date.getFullYear();

                    var currentdate = (m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y;
                    for (var i = 0; i < disableddates.length; i++) {

                        // Now check if the current date is in disabled dates array. 
                        if ($.inArray(currentdate, disableddates) != -1) {
                            return [false];
                        }
                    }
                    return [true];
                },

                autoclose: 1,
                todayHighlight: 1,
                startView: 2,
                minView: 2,
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Date:
        <input type="text" id="datepicker">
    </p>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```